# How to autocomplete twin character in linux terminal?

Tags: linux, autocomplete, editor, bash-completion

If I write "(" some editors autocomplete its twin ")" character. The same for apostrophes.
Is there anything safe I can do to make this happen in bash terminal?

Thank you

Comment: ctrl-x ctrl-e will edit your command line in your `$EDITOR`, if you were writing a long command.

Comment: thanks @Kent for the tip, that helps, but that doesn't solve 100% the issue.